# JavaScript function not running for form

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

http://pastebin.com/8n9jyMb3

There is the code. When I submit the form it doesn't run the validate() function. I have tried this exact thing with some different code and it works but for some freak reason it wont work right now. Please help. This ghost error is killing me.

Answer (score 1):

You have extra closing bracket.
Instead of

```
 else if(field.length) < 3)
```

should be

```
 else if(field.length < 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
`else if(field.length) < 3)  `
```

is not right syntax please correct this and remove extra closing bracket
replace above with this on

```
else if(field.length < 3)
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you. I guess it was a compile error or something because just that fixed it. Thanks :)